# Running EXE files in a folder sequence

Tags: python-2.7

I have a sequence of folders (planx 1 , planx 2 ,.......,planx 35) each folder contains an exe file `triton.exe`, I wrote the following code but it gives me a syntax error,apparently the format I wrote especially '+str(i)' is wrong.

I tried to correct that by adding " "before +str(i) but it reads the folder name (planx1) without space and surly there is no such folder.

what can I do to make it work ?

```
import sys, string, os
for i in range(1, 35):
    os.chdir( 'E:\\project\\x\\CR 0\\planx'+str(i))
    os.system( '"E:\\project\\x\\CR 0\\planx'+str(i)'\\triton.exe"')
print('done')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `+` after the `str(i)` to add the third string as well:

```
'...\planx'+str(i)+'\\trit...'
             #    ^ this one
```

although you may want to use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) instead of adding them together